# RegisterClientScriptCode not working after a partial post back

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, updatepanel

The following lines of code are in a user control in a SharePoint website.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "jquery144", "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/_layouts/Unicre.Web.RUOnline.Controlos/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js\"></script>", false);
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "javascriptgeral", "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/_layouts/Unicre.Web.RUOnline.Controlos/Scripts/javascript.js\"></script>", false);
```

Why doesn't it work? I also can't find the respective script tags in the HTML generated in the response.

The problem has to do with an update panel. After the partial postback, the Javascript stops working. Shouldn't it work with the above code?

(I also tried the RegisterClientScriptInclude method but with the same result.)

Comment: Hey independend from what the problem is, you have a typo here: <script type=\"text/javascript\"

Comment: OK, this embarrassing! I've been looking at it for quite sometime and I can't find the typo. Where is it?

Comment: Sorry my fault, everything is fine. Just mixed up a slash with a backslash. Sorry again :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't going to work on a partial postback. You need to register the scripts on `Page_Load`. In the user control, attach to the Load event and call ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock() from that handler.

> After the partial postback, the Javascript stops working

An UpdatePanel partial postback is DOM update of the UpdatePanel `<div>` contents. This means the previous contents are lost, so the state of inline script contained within that `<div>` loses its state.

See [here](http://www.jstawski.com/archive/2009/11/02/1230.aspx) for more information:

> UpdatePanel does its work on the client through the **innerHTML DOM property**. A delta is retrieved from the server, finds itself in the existing DOM, disposes of the contents, and then assigns the new content via innerHTML. ... But inline script doesn't work this way. Setting the innerHTML of a DOM element to HTML which contains a script block does not cause that script to execute.

Likewise, calling ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock() on an UpdatePanel update is not going to act like a page load. You could add the `<script>` elements directly to the UpdatePanel contents, but it won't execute.

**Update**

You can call javascript code after a partial postback by [adding an endRequest handler to the PageRequestManager](http://zeemalik.wordpress.com/2007/11/27/how-to-call-client-side-javascript-function-after-an-updatepanel-asychronous-ajax-request-is-over/):

```
<script>
function load() {
   //register the handler
   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
}
//this handler will execute after a partial postback
function EndRequestHandler(){
   //...arbitrary code...
}
window.onload = load; 
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry @Just M. Keyes, but I only see the reasons not to work. How should I make it work? BTW, I can execute an inline script function like HelloWorld(). But, in this case, what I need to do is to call a javascript file. How can I do such thing?

Comment: You need to call `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock()` on the initial server-side `Page_Load` (remember, this needs to be done every time, so don't check for `!IsPostBack`). Then, if there are specific functions that you want to run only after the UpdatePanel update, use the `add_endRequest()` approach shown in my updated answer above.

Comment: That is right and I was already using that callback. The problem is that I had to create duplicate code and that's why I would prefer to reference the JavaScript file, but at least the problem is solved. Thanks!

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I think that it is possible to use RegisterClientScriptBlock on an update panel, what the article you provide might mean is that you can't add script tags hard coded inside  and update panel, but anyway RegisterClientScriptBlock does work.