# Facebook Like & Google +1 button disappears on partial postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook, facebook-like, google-plus-one

I have place facebook like and google + buttons inside a webpart which in turn is inside an update panel. The problem is that once an asynchronous postback is made through update panel, the fb and g+ buttons disappear.

I also have a twitter button in it with which i had face similar issue earlier. It now works after I have placed the twitter javascript outside the update panel:

```
<asp:updatepanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
     <asp:WebPartManager ID="WebPartManager1" runat="server">
     </asp:WebPartManager>
     <script type="text/javascript">              
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequest);                
     </script>
     <asp:webpartzone ID="WebPartZone1" runat="server" PartChromeType="None" >
       <ZoneTemplate>
       .
       .
       .
        <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none">Tweet Profile</a><br />
        <div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=181772605219534&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="" send="false" layout="button_count" width="50" show_faces="false" font="trebuchet ms"></fb:like>
        <br/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
        <g:plusone size="medium" count="true"></g:plusone>
         .
         .
         </ZoneTemplate>
     </asp:webpartzone>
     <asp:webpartzone ID="WebPartZone2" runat="server" Width="100%" 
                            PartChromeType="None">
         .
         .
         .
     </asp:webpartzone>
</asp:updatepanel>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        $.getScript("http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js");
    }
</script>
```

This reloaded the broken javascript after partial postback for twitter tweet button and it works fine. But the same doesn't happen for facebook and google plus buttons, when i replace the javascripts. I am using ASP.NET 4 and c#. How can I fix this??

Comment: Did you try RegisterStartupScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegisterClientScriptCode not working after a partial post back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652024/registerclientscriptcode-not-working-after-a-partial-post-back)

Comment: No that didn't work. Pl check my edited question. Can u be specific how should i use it for the buttons above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UpdatePanel updates its contents by setting the `innerHTML` property. This means any DOM state within the UpdatePanel element is lost after an UpdatePanel async postback. The fb, g+, and twitter buttons all are working with the DOM state of your UpdatePanel `div`, which the server obliterates when it sends the `innerHTML` delta to the client.

See my answer here: [RegisterClientScriptCode not working after a partial post back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652024/registerclientscriptcode-not-working-after-a-partial-post-back/6652747#6652747)

You need to disable async postback for the webpart, or put the scripts somewhere else.

**Updated Question**

Did you try this? Remove the `<script>` elements and call them using jquery:

```
<asp:updatepanel............>
     <asp:WebPartManager ID="WebPartManager1" runat="server" />
     <asp:webpartzone...........>
       .
       .
       .
        <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none">Tweet Profile</a><br />
        <div id="fb-root"></div><fb:like href="" send="false" layout="button_count" width="50" show_faces="false" font="trebuchet ms"></fb:like><br/>
        <g:plusone size="medium" count="true"></g:plusone>
     </asp:webpartzone>
</asp:updatepanel>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        $.getScript("http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js");
        $.getScript("http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=181772605219534&amp;xfbml=1");
        $.getScript("https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js");
    }
</script>
```

If that doesn't work, why not just separate the buttons into a static panel? The buttons have no use for an UpdatePanel. Something like this:

```
<!-- webpartmanager does NOT need to enclose your webparts. 
     Just declare it. -->
<asp:webpartmanager ... /> 

<!-- asp:updatepanel contains the async webpart. -->
<asp:updatepanel ...> 
    <asp:WebPartZone id="WebPartZone1" runat="server">
      <ZoneTemplate>
        ...
      </ZoneTemplate>
    </asp:WebPartZone>
</asp:updatepanel>

<!-- another webpart holds the buttons, NOT contained by updatepanel. -->
<asp:WebPartZone id="WebPartZone2" runat="server">
  <ZoneTemplate>
    <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none">Tweet Profile</a><br />
    <div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=181772605219534&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="" send="false" layout="button_count" width="50" show_faces="false" font="trebuchet ms"></fb:like><br/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
    <g:plusone size="medium" count="true"></g:plusone>
  </ZoneTemplate>
</asp:WebPartZone>
```

Comment: The fb button disappears if i separate the javascript from it in my case

Comment: I meant you need to move the buttons entirely somewhere else--not in an UpdatePanel.

Comment: But I have to to use them inside Update Panel. Tweet button now works pretty well which was facing the same problem. There must be a way to make fb and google buttons work too.

Comment: Yes, I did the same. When i do so the fb and +1 buttons disappers whereas the twitter button remains.. And i need asyn postback for webparts which is why i have kept it inside update panel. How do i separate them into static panel when in gui i need them inside the webpart??

Comment: Use two different webparts--one webpart in an updatepanel, and one that contains the buttons. BTW, there is no need to wrap everything in `<asp:webpartmanager>`, it just needs to be somewhere on the page.

Comment: Sorry, it was webpartzone not manager. Update the code... I have >1 webpartzones in the code and these set of buttons need to be in this specific webpartzone which has other controls too apart from the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

This may appear to be highly unusual solution, but this worked for chrome and firefox.

It worked when i kept the javascript src link for facebook both inside the update panel and also oustide the update panel (jquery call). For the Twitter and Google + buttons it requires to be only called by jquery outside the update panel. It worked when i used the following combination:

```
<asp:updatepanel............>
 <asp:WebPartManager ID="WebPartManager1" runat="server">
 </asp:WebPartManager>
 <asp:webpartzone...........>
   .
   .
   .
    <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none">Tweet Profile</a><br />
    <div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=181772605219534&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="" send="false" layout="button_count" width="50" show_faces="false" font="trebuchet ms"></fb:like>
    <br/>
    <g:plusone size="medium" count="true"></g:plusone>
     .
     .
 </asp:webpartzone>
 <asp:webpartzone ..........>
     .
     .
     .
 </asp:webpartzone>
</asp:updatepanel>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function pageLoad() {
    $.getScript("http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js");          
    $.getScript("http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=181772605219534&amp;xfbml=1");
    $.getScript("https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js");
            }
</script>
```

**NOTE:** The google +1 button still doesn't work in Internet Explorer but all 3 buttons work fine on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Yes, that's almost the same as my answer. `pageLoad()` is re-running on each async postback. You could take the buttons out of the updatepanel with some creative HTML and CSS.

Comment: @Justin Then edit your answer as same. Please provide solution of how to use the creative html part. This isn't the final solution as g+ button is still not working for IE....

Comment: I'd need to see your other elements (which you snipped "..." for brevity). Remember that an UpdatePanel is just a `div`, so take out the buttons, break up the async elements into multiple UpdatePanels if needed, and you can achieve the layout you want...

Answer (score 0):

I always exclude them from partial postback. All ads, +1 and like buttons are excluded from update panel.